# Avoid cell autoresizing in editing mode iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, editing, autoresize, custom-cell

I have a problem with my custom cells.
My cell is structured like this image:
[image]

Gray view = cell.contentView
Orange view = a button added as a subview to the contentView
Yellow view = a label added as subview to the contentView
Blue view = an image view added as subview to the contentView
Green view = accessory view

The problem is that when I toggle edit to tableView, my cell indents hiding accessory view and moving right everything else. I want to **avoid** this.
When I toggle editing mode, my cell mustn't move its content, the editing control (minus red button on the left) must take the place of the button inside the contentView and this last one should hide itself.

I tried `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` method without success because my tableView is plain. I also tried to override `willTransitionToState:` method but I don't know how to do what I want.

Can someone help me?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How have you added the subviews to the cell? If you add them directly to the cell instead of adding them to the content view, they won't get moved. It is the content view that is resized when the cell transitions to editing mode.

If you want to hide certain subviews, you should override `setEditing:animated:` in the cell subclass and hide / show as appropriate.

You may also need to add your subviews such that they are below the contentView in the view hierarchy, or bring the content view to the top after you have finished, using the `bringSubviewToFront:` method.

Comment: Yes, I've added them in the contentView because I know that this is the best way... However, can I add them directly to the cell?

Comment: You can indeed. Content View is "the best way" because it gives you the resizing and rearrangement, so for you, it isn't actually the best way at all!

Comment: Ok... It works well but when I show the delete button on the right, it is shown behind the image view added to the cell (blue view in the image above)

Comment: Added a bit more to the answer. I think the content view is where the delete button is added, so you need to make sure your other views are "behind" this. I also noticed your bit in the question about hiding the button, sorry I missed that before.

Comment: I've already overrode the setEditing:aminated: method and my code is like this: http://cl.ly/By0I in the layoutSubviews method I add my view as subviews to the cell...

Comment: You should definitely _not_ be adding subviews within `layoutSubviews`! They should only be moved in that method.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that... However, my label should resize based on some core data data and I add it as a subview in that method because not always it has to be shown...

Answer (score 2):

If you really don’t want the cell to resize, you could implement `-layoutSubviews` thusly:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    if ([self isEditing] == NO) {
        // Lay out subviews normally.
    }
}
```

When you go into edit mode, `-layoutSubviews` won’t follow the code path that lays out your views. This is assuming you’ve subclassed UITableViewCell.